# Who killed Professor Cal?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

Professor Cal was found murdered in his office. Luckily, security had been keeping tight track of all who entered and exited the building during the day, and were able to determine that the suspects are Gerry, Julie, Jason, Nicky, and Sophy.

Professor Cal, known for being helpful, but not too helpful, left a clue to identify his killer. On his calendar were written in blood the numbers 1, 4, 9, 10, 11.

Who killed Professor Cal?

Notes:

- Though not overly helpful, we must use the clue that Professor Cal left in its entirety to honor his memory.
- All aspects of the clue must be used.
- One of the five suspects committed the murder. Aside from Professor Cal's final clue, there are no other clues in the room.

Comment: Can't do a 1 character edit, but it should be "entirety", not "entirely"

Comment: Auxiliary note: I like the fact that he marked it on the Cal-endar, helpfully (though not too helpfully!) implying that the numbers implicated the ender of Cal.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's

> Jason

Because

> Taking the first letters of the months 1,4,9,10,11 spells out J(anuary), A(pril), S(eptember), O(ctober), N(ovember).

Comment: Well done. I'll accept in a little bit.

Answer (score 14):

> Use the numbers to figure out the month.
>  Initial letters of the month spell out JASON

Comment: Well done. Just beat out by Ivo.

Comment: Yeah.  I was trying to type out a long explanation at first.