# Who is the killer?

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, mystery

Keeping it short and crisp.

> A man was murdered in his office.
>
> The suspects are Gerry, Joseph, Jason, Nick, James and Sophie.
>
> The numbers 6, 4, 9, 10, 11 are written on a calendar with Blood.

**Who is the Killer?**

Comment: There is a similar question here, but I can't find!!

Comment: It's this one: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29445/who-killed-professor-cal

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The killer is

> Jason

Because

> Take the first letter of the month for the given numbers
>  6 -> June -> J
>  4 -> April -> A
>  9 -> September -> S
>  10 -> October -> O
>  11 -> November -> N

Answer (score 7):

Its

> JASON

Where

> The number represents the respective month in the calender.
>  6 gives **J**une
>  4 gives **A**pril
>  9 gives **S**eptember
>  10 gives **O**ctober
>  11 gives **N**ovember
>  Taking their first letters gives **JASON**.